# Rails: My page is rendering text results with html layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, text, render

My index page is rendering text result after html result.

```
[#<User id: 1, username: "mihracefendi", name: "Mihraç", bdate: nil, grad: nil, school: nil, city: nil, about: "Mikkembel bir oyuncu ve aynı zamanda seyis. Kendis...", created_at: "2017-10-04 15:49:54", updated_at: "2017-10-05 19:08:49", email: "mihracbey@gmail.com", avatar: "lohusa.jpg", gender: nil, lastname: "Cerrahoğlu">, #<User id: 2, ...>, ...]
```

[screen shot of index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVtHn.png)

Why is it happen and how i fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You should always include code when asking a "why is this happening?" or "why doesn't this work?" question. In this case, the culprit is probably your `_index.html.erb` - so you might want to edit your question to include that file. Otherwise, we're just speculating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have some code that looks something like:

```
<%= @users.each do |user| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Which, instead, should look like this:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes. Why did not i notice this? :/ So thanks dear.  I love this website!

Comment: Sure thing. Feel free to upvote/accept as you see fit. Good luck!